# Когда ставить двоеточие?

Tags: пунктуация

В каких случаях в предложении нужно ставить двоеточие?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Двоеточие ставится перед перечислением, находящимся на конце слова (часто употребляется или подразумевается выражением "как то", "а именно").
   Пример: *"На прилавке лежали фрукты: апельсины, бананы, яблоки"*.
2. Когда обощающего слова нет, но нужно дать понять, что далее следует перечисление.
   Пример: *"На витрине лежали: апельсины, бананы, яблоки"*.
3. Если перечисление находит в середине слова, то после перечисляемых предметов ставится тире.
   Пример: "*Фрукты: апельсины, бананы, яблоки - все это лежало на витрине"*.
4. В сложных предложениях, если второе является разъяснением первого.
   Пример: *"Я оказалась права: поезда туда не ходят"*.
5. В сложных предложениях, после слов "видеть", "смотреть", "знать", "слышать", "чувствовать".
   Пример: *"И вот, смотрю: вдоль дороги мертвые с косами стоят"*.
6. Перед прямой речью.
   Пример: *"Он сказал: "Приятно познакомиться"*.

Answer (score 0):

§112. Двоеточие в сложноподчиненном предложении

Двоеточие ставится перед подчинительным союзом в тех редких случаях, когда в предшествующей части сложного предложения содержится особое предупреждение о последующем разъяснении (в этом месте делается длительная пауза, а также можно вставить слова а именно), например: И, сделав это, почувствовал, что результат получился желаемый: что он тронут и она тронута (Л. Толстой); Он видел все: как вставала земля из пепла, непокоренная земля, неистребимая жизнь (Б. Горбатов).
в начало